# Make active tab text bold - DevExpress WinForm

Tags: winforms, devexpress-windows-ui

I want to make active tab text bold , tabs are DevExpress xtraTabs

So, wherever the DevExpress XTraTabs are used, make the text of active tab bold. 
Set this property once and not everywhere.How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the tabcontrol's `ApperancePage.HeaderActive.Font.Bold` property value to true.